# Will lime soda/borosilicate glass tubes glued/sealed with indium leak or crack?

Tags: vacuum, glass

I want to evacuate steam from a vacuum chamber with a dry ice or LN2 cold finger. I'm planning to connect the vacuum chamber and the cold finger via a tube. This inner tube will be glued/sealed with indium to the outer tube of the cold finger.

The inner tube is lime soda glass. The cold finger will be borosilicate glass. When I make the connection with molten indium at 157 C and let it cool, the inner tube will contract more than the outer tube. Will it leak?

When I want to disassemble it and heat the connection till the indium melts, the inner tube will expand more than the outer tube. Will it crack the cold finger? Can I avoid cracking if I make the outer tube hot faster than the inner tube?

The inner tube outer diameter is 10 mm.

Thank you!

[image: cold finger]

Comment: Why did my question get downvoted? Is it not a physics question? Is it more on topic in engineering? Or is it too hard or impossible to answer?

Comment: Probably one of those. Don't be discouraged, though it might be worth it looking whether there's a more appropriate SE (I can't tell).

Comment: Someone shrunk my pic. I hope you can still see enough detail.

Comment: Clicking on it brings the original picture.